# kubuntu 16.04: How to disable "tap to click" (using touchpad)?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

as above.

I'm looking at Settings => Input Devices => Touchpad but no settings seems obvious.

Thanks

Comment: try mouse settinngs

Comment: @ravery which settings? I'm looking at it and nothing obvious jumps out. thannks

Comment: It's been awhile since I used KDE but I think it was where the scroll speed is at.

Answer (score 0):

Under "Touchpad Settings" there should be a "Taps" tab where you can disable "Mouse Click Emulation" by setting the selection for "One finger:" to "No action" from the dropdown menu.